# Why is investing in China higher risk than Europe?

Tags: investment-strategies

This is a fund of Asian tech companies mostly in China.
https://select.bestinvest.co.uk/fund-factsheets/fidinemp/fidelity-index-emerging-markets-p/inc#Portfolio

and this is a mix of EU investments
https://select.bestinvest.co.uk/fund-factsheets/hsbceurc/hsbc-european-index-c/acc#Portfolio

There are a number of EU funds with 5 stars but I could only find one focused on China with 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emerging market funds tend to be include younger companies.  I.e. companies are more likely to have only been possible recently in emerging markets, as more established markets have more established companies.

China has risks that are less likely in the European Union.  For example, it is a real risk that China might nationalize a critical company for a below market price.  In a European country, the other countries of Europe would tend to prevent that, as some of their investors would be impacted.  Even if the nationalization went through, it is more likely that the price would be made more reasonable, possibly through court action.  In China, that would be more of an internal, non-judicial decision.

Europe has more of a history of stability.  China has a reputation for growth, but growth won't last forever.  It is likely to go through a stagnant period sometime.  This typically happens around the time we stop calling a country developing and start calling it developed.  Japan is a recent example.